# Assign a value to drop down list on page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I'm trying to assign value to a drop down list on the page_load, but it's not automatically get selected when the page loads up. But when I try to select another value from the drop down list, then the value assigned to it originally gets selected. I think it's something to do with the PostBack, My code is,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["selectedReg"]))
    {
        string selectedReg = Request.QueryString["selectedReg"];
        ddlVehicleReg.SelectedIndex = ddlVehicleReg.Items.IndexOf(ddlVehicleReg.Items.FindByText(selectedReg));
    }
```

If I use if(!IsPostBack) still no luck, Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code block you have written is working. No need to check for postback. Be careful about your `querystring`. It looks like these pictures for my tests.

[image]
[image]

After your comment I changed `dropdown` item list. It is getting data from database. And I called this method in `Page_Load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillDropDown();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["selectedReg"]))
        {
            string selectedReg = Request.QueryString["selectedReg"];
            ddlVehicleReg.SelectedIndex = ddlVehicleReg.Items.IndexOf(ddlVehicleReg.Items.FindByText(selectedReg));
        }
    }

   protected void FillDropDown()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("server=.;database=StackTest;integrated security=true") )
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Test", con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
            adp.Fill(dt);

            ddlVehicleReg.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlVehicleReg.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlVehicleReg.DataSource = dt;
            ddlVehicleReg.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Murat thanks a lot for your answer. I'm populating the ddlVehicleReg from the datasource. If the items are added as you have shown above it works. but not when it is populated through a datasource. Any idea why?

Comment: @KMR OK I have changed my post. It is also working. Please give more information about what you have done before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine now. you were right. The data source for the ddl needed to be re-assigned in the page_load.